# Adding .txt, .png and other options for savecommand

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, save

So I have started a minor text editor project in python 3 and I have managed to add a save button with a function to save the document, but I want to add the options of choosing between .txt, .png and other for the save command. How could I do that?

```
from tkinter import *   # Imports everything from tkinter
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog


class Window(Frame):    # Frame is a class in tkineter and we are creating a 
frame or a window
    def __init__(self, master=None):    
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master    #Mainframe or main window

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):  # 

        self.master.title("GUI")    #windows title is GUI

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)  # Adjust window as we want, but also 
fill up the window as a defult


        menu =Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Open File')
        file.add_command(label='New File')
        file.add_command(label='Save as')
        file.add_command(label='Save', command=self.file_save)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)

        edit = Menu(menu)
        edit.add_command(label='Undo')
        edit.add_command(label='Redo')
        menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=edit)


    def file_save(self):
        f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
        if f is None:
            return
        text2save = str(text.get(1.0, END))
        f.write(text2save)
        f.close()

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()


root = Tk()     # 
root.geometry("400x300")    #Specify the dimention of the window as 400 by 
300
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()     # Generates our window for us
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `asksaveasfile`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm) you can see there's a `filetypes` parameter. Simply fill that with a list of the file types you want.

```
filetypes_choices = [('Text file', '*.txt'), ('PNG Image File', '*.png')]
f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=filetypes_choices)
```

Comment: That was what i was looking for! Thank you! But i also wonder, when i hit save the command prompt returns "name 'text' is not defined" in the `text2save = str(text.get(1.0, END))`, but the file still saves as a text document!

Comment: @Hernes97 I'm afraid I can't help you with that problem. It does seem odd that you get an error yet the code appears to produce a result. Are you sure the file didn't already exist?

Comment: The file does not exist unless i save the file